# Docker not mapping changes from local project to the container in windows

Tags: docker

I am trying to use Docker volume/bind mount so that I don't need to build my project again and again after every small change. I do not get any error but changes in the local files are not visible in container thus I still have to rebuild the project for the new files system snapshot.

Following solution seemed to work for some people.Therefore,

I have tried restarting Docker and Reset Credentials at Docker Desktop-->Setting-->Shared Drives

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
 web:
   build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
   volumes:
     - /app/node_modules
     - .:/app
```

I have tried through Docker CLI too. but problem persists

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .

docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v ${pwd}:/app image-id
```

Windows does copy the files in current directory to container but they are 
not in sync

I am using Windows 10 power shell and docker version  18.09.2

**UPDATE:**

I have checked container contents 
using command

```
 docker exec -t -i container-id sh
```

and the printed file contents using command

```
cat filename
```

And from this it is clear that the files container references to has/have changed/updated but I still don't understand why do i have to restart container to see the changes in browser.

Should not they be apparent after just refreshing the tab?

Comment: I guess you just restart container only `docker restart container_name`,if you want the change effected

Comment: Thanks. restarting the container only works . Although according to the tutorial "Docker and Kubernetes the Complete Guide" on Udemy previous method should work.
Do you know how can i make the container restart itself?

Comment: so you want container is automatically restart once code changed?

Comment: yes. Once any code changes docker detects that change and restarts the container.